# Search MySQL table based on optional form inputs

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to write a function for my customer system that can search the "customers" table based on one (or more) inputs from the search form.  The code is posted below

```
$lookupCust['userid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['userid']);
$lookupCust['name'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
$lookupCust['phone'] =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['phone']);
$lookupCust['balance'] =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['balance']);
$lookupCust['credit'] =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['credit']);
$lookupCust['notes'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['notes']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 
            userid = '" . $lookupCust['userid'] . "' OR
            name = '" . $lookupCust['name'] . "' OR
            phone = '" . $lookupCust['phone'] . "' OR
            balance = '" . $lookupCust['balance'] . "' OR
            credit = '" . $lookupCust['credit'] . "' OR
            notes = '" . $lookupCust['notes'] . "'";
$lookupCust['result'] = '<table border="1"><tr><td>Username</td><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td><td>Balance</td><td>Credit</td><td>Notes</td></tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $lookupCust['result'] .= "<tr><td>".$row['userid']."</td><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['phone']."</td><td>".$row['balance']."</td><td>".$row['credit']."</td><td>".$row['notes']."</td></tr>";
```

The problem here is that no matter what gets typed in, all the customers will be listed out, due to the query having blank spaces (from fields that aren't filled in).  Can someone write an example on how to search only what is submitted to the query?

Comment: Consider using an `if(empty` condition and STOP them right at the front gate.

Comment: If you like typing extra, stick to this technique, otherwise I would use `new mysqli()` and the Object Oriented approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code something like this:

```
$where = "";

foreach ($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    if ($v == "")
        continue;

    if ($where != "")
        $where .= "OR ";

    $where .= $k ." = '".mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($v))."'";
}
```

If `$_POST` has other than search keywords. you can do that like this:

```
$search = Array('userid', 'name', 'phone', 'balance', 'credit', 'notes');

$where = "";

foreach ($search as $col)
{
    if ($_POST[$col] == "")
        continue;

    if ($where != "")
        $where .= "OR ";

    // $where .= $col ." LIKE '".mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST[$col]))."%'"; // prefix matching

    // $where .= $col ." LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST[$col]))."%'"; //   matches anywhere
}
```

FYI, I think search by POST method is not good practice. difficult to make a permanent link url. this is not user-friendly.

Comment: Ran it.  The $where produced: = 'bill' OR OR OR OR OR  when i typed in "bill" as a userid.  How am I supposed to make a query out of this?

Comment: @AlexSchittko sorry, I made mistakes.. Need to change "OR" and "continue" block. also I added `trim()` to remove white space. answer updated.

Comment: Adjusted $k to $col in the 2nd snippet.  Works great, except I'm running into the same problem as the other answer.  The results only produce exact matches.  IE, i search "alex" and only "alex" comes out.  I'd like for this to also display "alex4" and "alex5" and any other partial matches.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlexSchittko thanks for correcting my typo. are you looking for `LIKE` operator rather than `=` (equal)? I have updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `&&` or `AND` condition, like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 
  userid = '{$lookupCust['userid']}' && userid != '' ||
  name = '{$lookupCust['name']}' && name != '' ||
  phone = '{$lookupCust['phone']}' && phone != '' ||
  balance = '{$lookupCust['balance']}' && balance != '' || 
  credit = '{$lookupCust['credit']}' && credit != '' ||
  notes = '{$lookupCust['notes']}' && notes != ''";
```

I took the liberty to show you a technique in double quotes to save keystrokes. Also, you should make sure to check your [mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php). There is a good example of OOP style at that link. You should keep your database connection on a secure separate page, though.

Comment: shouldn't you group each AND condition with ()? Just asking.

Comment: Just ran this.  It only works if I type in the exact value, so it's not theoretically a "search".  I changed the ='s to LIKE but that didn't change anything.  I then added %'s around the '{$variable}'s and that just produced a SQL error